# iOS text file corrupt when sent via Google hosted mail server to Mac / iOS email client

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, email

I create a text file in an iOS app and email it as an attachment. I receive it on a Mac (or iOS client). If the emails is sent to an Apple hosted mailbox (e.g. xxx@me.com) all is fine. If the file is sent to a Google hosted mail account such as xxx@mydomain.com it is corrupt (big time).

This is the code:

```
....

MFMailComposeViewController* mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mailController setSubject:@"Some subject"];
[mailController setMessageBody:@" " isHTML:NO];
[mailController addAttachmentData:fileAsData mimeType:@"text/plain" fileName:@"filename.txt"];

....
```

To make it even more confusing if is send the email to a GMAIL hosted account (e.g. xxx@gmail.com) all is fine.

Finally if I use the standard mail client on an iPad / iPhone and attach the very same file from an iCloud Drive using the new iOS9 "Add Attachment" functionality for attaching files all is fine.

So I figure that it is a combination of (1) how I create the email and attach the file programatically and the (2) the Google email hosting service. Maybe I just can't see the wood for the trees.